# How to get new records from second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

df1:

| StationName | RunID | ScheduledDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 12345 | 2021-08-12 |
| BBB | 23456 | 2021-08-12 |
| DDD | 91273 | 2021-07-15 |

df2:

| StationName | RunID | ScheduledDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 12345 | 2021-08-12 |
| BBB | 23456 | 2021-08-12 |
| AAA | 65323 | 2021-07-20 |
| MMM | 14526 | 2021-05-20 |

I would like to get the new records from df2 using the RunID column while eliminating any duplicate records found from df1.

Expected output, df3:

| StationName | RunID | ScheduledDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 65323 | 2021-07-20 |
| MMM | 14526 | 2021-05-20 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `merge()` with `indicator=True` and `query()` to filter out result and `drop()` to drop extra column:

```
out=(df1[['RunID']].merge(df2,on='RunID',how='outer',indicator=True)
                   .query("_merge=='right_only'").drop(columns='_merge'))
```

**Note:** you can also do right merge by passing `how='right'`

output of `out`:

```
    RunID   StationName     ScheduledDate
3   65323   AAA             2021-07-20
4   14526   MMM             2021-05-20
```